# Chaining associated objects won't allow me to call their attributes Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, associations

I'm in need of some help. I have been making a blog site in Rails to work on some gems and other techniques and I ran into a problem. I am calling a comment partial into my blog show page as shown here:

show.html.slim:

```
- if notice != nil
p#notice.alert.alert-success role='alert' = notice

h1 Blog Post

h4 Title: #{@blog_post.title}

h4 Author: #{@blog_post.user.name}

h4 Entry:
p = @blog_post.blog_entry

= render partial: 'comments/form', locals: { comment: @comment }

.panel.panel-default
  .panel-heading
    h4 Comments
  #js-comments.panel-body
    = render partial: 'comments/comment', collection: @blog_post.comments

= link_to 'Feed', blog_posts_path, class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

The issue is in the comments/comment partial:

```
.panel-body
  p
    strong
      = comment.user.username
    |  said at 
    span.posted-at
      = comment.created_at.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    | : 
  p = comment.comment_entry
  - if policy(comment).update?
    = link_to 'Edit Comment', edit_blog_post_comment_path(comment.blog_post, comment), class: 'btn btn-primary'
  - if policy(comment).destroy?
    = link_to 'Destroy Comment', [comment.blog_post, comment], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

Now when I call comment.user.username or comment.created_at.strftime, I got NoMethodError messages saying that username and strftime are undefined methods. However, if I call comment.user and comment.created_at, it works just fine. For some reason it just won't let me add that additional method to the chain. I can verify that all the correct associations are in place between the user, blog_post, and comments.

Just in case, here is my blog controller for the show page:

```
def show
  @comment = @blog_post.comments.new
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT:

The error message is:

```
undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass
```

and better_errors is telling me the issue is on the comment partial at

```
comment.user.username
```

and on the show page where it is calling the partial

```
= render partial: 'comments/comment', collection: @blog_post.comments
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the variable `comment` in your partial?

Comment: Additionally you are not calling attributes - you are calling chained methods - some of the happen to be getters for attributes. But its a pretty important distinction.

Comment: I have, and if I remove username and strftime from the method chains, it actually works, which is what seems so weird to me.

Comment: Can you post the error and stack trace.

Comment: I just posted it as an edit in the original post. I hope that helps some

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment initialized in the controller is added to @blog_post.comments but it has no user or created_at. Simply change your controller to `@comment = Comment.new`